# Where to download JRockit for Java 1.5

Tags: java, jvm, jrockit, java-5

I checked on download page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/downloads/index.html but only versions for java 6 are available.

Comment: Does the answer here help at all? It doesn't look like they have it for download officially anywhere. http://groups.google.com/group/javaposse/browse_thread/thread/d41e7c28d6cc532d

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I could use the metalink.oracle.com site, since it seems to require the incident number as first thing

Comment: I'm not sure either, I'd personally take the support request route to Oracle to ask!

Comment: Why do you want to download an old version for Java 5 only?

Comment: I need Java 5 because the project I'm working on doesn't work with java 6. Is it possible to use last version in "java 5 mode"?

Comment: Please post the Java 5 code which fails to compile under Java 6

Comment: I have some library problem, it is not just a problem on some lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it is distributed via a patch: Patch 11931215: JDK150 ORACLE JROCKIT R28.1.3
Request it to Oracle Support

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is still relevant. I was on a similar hunt and first stumbled on this question, then later figured out the following with the help of oracle support:

1. Go to [Oracle Software Delivery Cloud](http://edelivery.oracle.com) - you will have to register/sign in.
2. For Product Pack select "Oracle BEA"
3. Select the platform of your choice.
4. Click on “BEA WebLogic Media Pack for..."
5. You will see three JRockit links for different java versions. Pick
   the one you need-

Answer (score 1):

It might help. It helped me. JRockit are downloaded from the below specified site. Clicking on the download link you will get the latest version something like this. From this you can specify the version on the copied link address and hit in the browsers.

http://download.oracle.com/otn/bea/jrockit/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_37-R28.2.5-4.1.0-windows-ia32.exe

http://download.oracle.com/otn/bea/jrockit/jrockit---.

Note : To use this you have to know the version exactly .

Answer (score 0):

I found that the last publicly still "available" is version 1.5.0_30
link is http://download.oracle.com/otn/bea/jrockit/jrockit-jdk1.5.0_30-R28.1.4-4.0.1-windows-ia32.exe

- go to any oracle java download first e.g. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html
- click any of the download
- checked the license agreement
- inspect the download button
- replace the href with above jrockit link
- close inspect mode and click download.